# Decrypt EFS-encrypted file (I do have certificate backup)

Tags: windows, ntfs, efs

I have an encrypted folder on a Windows 8 machine, which was encrypted by another user-account (which I cannot boot into due to a corrupted profile).

But **I do have the private-key backup certificate** in a PFX file and I'm the local administrator. Any way I can decrypt the folder?

Comment: You should be able to have you even tried?

Comment: @Ramhound How exactly? When I clear the "encrypt" checkbox I get an "access denied" error

Comment: You need to import the backup certificate; check this article out: [How to Restore the Encrypted File System (EFS) Certificate in Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/99956-encrypted-file-system-efs-certificate-restore.html). Then report back.

Comment: @and31415 I did that. Still - "access denied" when I remove the "encrypt contents" checkbox in the file attributes

Comment: @jitbit I'm in exactly the same situation. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Basic nope, sorry :(

Comment: Use CIPHER.EXE /? to examine the thumbprints of the encrypted files and CERTMGR.MSC to verify your imported certificate matches.